# Multiple substitutions in a single text

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to write such a formula that it will substitute in a text value all occurrences of few values with their replacements?

For example I would like to substitute all occurrences of `aaa` with `1` and `bbb` with `2`. So that text `aaabbbaaa` will be changed to `121`.

---

I have prepared an [example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Au9MjrJNgPESdHgzUkE2Qm4yekJiV1NxOEhvUW9NQXc&usp=sharing) which also has write access so feel free to add a column with your formula and in the answer just explain it. Also you can add new test cases.

---

In my “real world” case the look-up table is quite large (45 values) but could be considered “fixed”. So yes, I could just make a formula consisting of 45 nested `SUBSTITUTE` but such solution is obviously bad.

Also my real case is not as tricky as the example so there is no risk that replacement text will in any way match (even in parts) any of the values to be substituted. (In the example `ddd` is replaced with `a` which matches partially value `aaa`!) So if that causes problems you might skip the “feature”.

And finally in my real case I'm lucky enough to be able to split the text into parts which contain no more than one value to be replaced (and possibly some other character data!). The result could be then joined back into a single string. If that would make it any easier you could use that as well.

---

I tried using both `SUBSTITUTE` and `REGEXREPLACE` where text to be found and replacement text are arrays of values but that results in an array of results rather than multiple substitutions.

I tried also using `REGEXREPLACE` with `VLOOKUP` in replacement text that looked up for `"$1"` (the matched text) but that didn't work. The `"$1"` within `VLOOKUP` within `REGEXREPLACE` was treated literally rather than interpreted as matched text (as it would be if it was used in `REGEXREPLACE` directly).

Comment: I also asked the question on Google forums: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/docs/spreadsheets/how-do-i/desktop/EheJ_dlRUH4.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As discussed in the thread you linked to in comments, the formula solution is quite convoluted and potentially very slow, if there are multiple instances to be replaced in the string. However with your qualification:

> And finally in my real case I'm lucky enough to be able to split the
>   text into parts which contain no more than one value to be replaced
>   (and possibly some other character data!). The result could be then
>   joined back into a single string. If that would make it any easier you
>   could use that as well.

I believe the solution becomes a little more straight forward (and reasonably efficient, I would say):

`=IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(A2;JOIN("|";Lookup!$A$2:$A$5);VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2;JOIN("|";Lookup!$A$2:$A$5));Lookup!$A$2:$B$5;2;0)&"");A2)`

which has the added advantage of being able to be easily converted into an array formula that will populate down the column:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A;JOIN("|";Lookup!A2:A5);VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A;JOIN("|";Lookup!A2:A5));Lookup!A2:B5;2*SIGN(ROW(A2:A));0)&"");A2:A))`

I have also entered a custom function solution:

```
function MSUBSTITUTE(text, subTable)
{
  var searchArray = [], subArray = [];
  for (var i = 0, length = subTable.length; i < length; i++)
  {
    if (subTable[i][0])
    {
      searchArray.push(subTable[i][0]);
      subArray.push(subTable[i][1]);
    }
  }
  var re = new RegExp(searchArray.join('|'), 'g');
  return text.replace(re, function (match) {return subArray[searchArray.indexOf(match)];});
}
```

`=MSUBSTITUTE(A2;Lookup!$A$2:$B$5)`

It would be fairly trivial to convert this to an auto-populating array formula, as well.

Comment: Any future reader: also see more discussion on the Google forums: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/docs/spreadsheets/how-do-i/desktop/EheJ_dlRUH4

Comment: Apparently the first formula should end with `1;0)&"");A2)` not `2;0)&"");A2)` (The "2" changes to a "1"). I haven't tested this myself, but you might want to double check.

Answer (score 2):

This custom function can be reduced to:

```
function multipass(text, ChangeFrom, ChangeTo) {
  ChangeFrom = ChangeFrom.map (String);
  var re = new RegExp(ChangeFrom.join('|'), 'g');
  return text.replace(re, function (match) {return ChangeTo[ChangeFrom.indexOf(match)];});
}
```

The key thing is `ChangeFrom.map (String)` which is necessary because although the range is converted to an array, its elements are not converted to Strings. It's essential to use `String` not `toString` in this line or the `indexOf` will fail.

For example:

```
=multipass(D5, Changes!A1:A10, Changes!B1:B10)
```

In this example, the result will be whatever was in D5, with substitutions made from the 2 columns `Changes!A1:A10` and `Changes!B1:B10`. In practice these would be named columns, but have used references to make it clearer.

(I called it `multipass` in honour of 5th Element :)